# How will filter(kernel) size affect the Transpose Convolution operation(ConvTranspose2d in Pytorch)?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

Will larger kernel help upsample with better detail or a small sized kernel? And how would padding fit in this scenario?